# How to bevel loop cut weighted edges only on a default cube?

Tags: bevel

I want **only** the selected and weighted edges to be bevelled. What must I change in order get working?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like beveling an edge in *Edit Mode* where you can split a single edge in multiple edges? That's not possible with the *Bevel* modifier.

For "normal" beveling, to make use of the *Bevel Weight* applied to certain edges you have to set the *Limit Method* in the modifier to *Weight* instead of *Vertex Group*.